# Short-lived vs Long-lived for static data

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I understand how the generational garbage collection HotSpot JVM uses works. We have a method that returns a list of static data, along the lines of

```
public List<String> getList() {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    ret.add("foo");
    ret.add("bar");
    return ret;
}
```

I was considering rewriting this as

```
private static List<String> list = null;
...
public List<String> getList() {
    if (list == null) { .. initialize here .. }
    return list;
}
```

this would only create the list once. This single list instance would eventually make its way into the tenured generation. Since this is a rather large app, using this design pattern in many places would mean there are a lot of these static lists in the tenured generation - increasing memory usage of the app.

If we follow the pattern of creating and returning a new list every time, said list would never make it out of eden before being garbage collected. There would be a bit more work involved - having to create and fill the list, and work in garbage collecting - but we would use less memory overall since the list doesn't last long.

This question is more academic in nature, as either pattern will work. Storing a static list will increase memory usage by an insignificant amount, and creating the list every time will increase workload by an insignificant amount. Which pattern to use probably depends on a number of factors - how often the list is used, how much memory pressure the app is under, etc. Which pattern would you guys target, andy why?

Comment: Oh the never-ending-tradeoff of time vs space :P

Comment: One thing to consider is that storing a static list is more bug-prone - callers to that method could modify the return value, etc. In general you shouldn't try to outsmart the GC.

Comment: When you store long term data, make sure it's immutable. A few lists here and there won't make your working set that large, and you probably already have long-term objects anyway (services, DAO, whatever).

Comment: If this list will never, ever change, *and is expensive to create*, it makes sense to keep a single copy. But, to Frank Pavageau's comment, be sure to wrap it with `Collections.unmodifiableList()`.

Answer (score 4):

> Storing a static list will increase memory usage by an insignificant amount

It will use more space when there is no real need for it. It will be the same if there is one usage of it. But if you have more than one copy, the static version is more efficient.

Often it's not the best case which will kill you, it's the worst case. In the worst case there will be large numbers ?millions? of copies of the collection.

Comment: It is true that the amount of memory used will be the same, since it is the same list with the same content. The kicker is the amount of time that memory is in use; if I keep a static list then that memory is reserved for the life of the jvm, whereas a short lived list can be garbage collected. Good note about the worst case though, I had not considered that

Answer (score 0):

As Peter Lawrey points out, in the non-static case, sometimes you will be using a lot more memory than necessary while the GC is waiting to do its thing.

I would concentrate on what's more readable. To me, Guava's `ImmutableList.of` in a `static final` field says immediately this data isn't going to change.

(Or `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(...))` if you don't want Guava)